# Datagridview Cell text disappears when editing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am building a winform application in C#. I am using `DataGridView` to populate the data. However, when I try to edit it, the cell content just disappears. Only when I click on the other cell, the text reappears.

Any idea, why is it happening and how to fix it. Attached is the screenshot of the  `DataGridView` when the text is disappeared.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using DataBinding to bind the grid, or are you manually populating each row?

Comment: Are those colors done with cell styles or by custom painting in an event handler like `CellPainting`?  In any case, we'd need more code to help further.  Standard `DataGridViews` don't have this problem, so it must be something you've added to it.  My guess is that text color == cell highlight back color.

Comment: HI, I am not using DataBinding. I am manually populating each row. I changed the `RowsDefaultCellStyle` to highlight the text. I will just if text color  is same as the cell highlight color

Comment: Are you populating the data into a DataTable?  Can you show the code for how you are manually populating the rows please?

Answer (score 0):

It is because when the cell is selected the foreground colour is the same as the cell background colour.

The fix is to change the selection foreground colour. So on the data grid properties look for `DefaultCellStyle`, and change the `SelectionForeColor` from `HighlightText` (which is white on my system) to something other than white (black would seem an obvious choice). You can also set it on the column rather than the entire grid, in which case right click on the grid and select `Edit Columns` and it is again `DefaultCellStyle` that you want to edit.

In my case the `DefaultCellStyle` on the grid was `SelectBackColor` = `Highlight` (blue) and `SelectForeColor` = `HighlightText` (white) so on the face of it I would have expected the text still to be visible. (The column settings were just using the grid default.) Yet I'm seeing white on white. So there is more to this, but the solution remains to tinker with the `SelectionForColor`.